# using move_uploaded_file and assigning the file a unique name

Tags: php, file-upload, uniqueidentifier

How can I insert a unique name into

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to give the file a unique name/identifier? It needs to correlate with

```
$file_link = "http://www.website.com/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

as the last var def is inserted into SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might wan to assign a name based on a datime

```
$name = date('Ymdhis') . '.yourextenctionhere';
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = $name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```